# fsck -fy doesn't fix filesystem errors

Tags: filesystem, ext4, fsck

When I run fsck.ext4 -fy /dev/sda2 I get lot of errors like that:

```
'..' in /Martin/Videa (58329818) is <The NULL inode> (0), should be /Martin (26476545).
```

No other type of error appears, not even after mounting, unmounting and checking again.

Anyone knows how to fix these?

Comment: Have you tried the `-p` flag?

Comment: After trying the -pf flags, it complains about unexpected inconsistency with the same type of error message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, badblocks with writing enabled finds bad blocks on every attempt after rebooting. It is said that drives reallocate bad sectors themselves nowadays. This one not only has bad sectors always, but reallocated sector count is equal to zero according to S.M.A.R.T, regardless how many times I run badblocks.

It's interesting that once I set the number of tests badblocks perform to more than one, the first test found bad blocks, but subsequent tests found none. The bad blocks reappeared after reboot.

Once I've even cancelled the test and the drive stopped responding for a few days. (ATA error)

May someone explain that to me? (Disappearing and reappearing of bad blocks and especially the fact that the drive stopped responding and started responding again after few days.)